# C++ URDL Compile Errors with Xcode 6.1 / LLVM 6.0

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, clang, boost-asio

I want to include the C++ Libary called [URDL](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html). I am developing a program on Xcode with Clang Compiler using Boost 1.56.

As a Sample Project I used this code here and include the Boost Libaries- and Include-Paths in the settings of my Xcode Project.

```
#include <iostream> 

#define URDL_HEADER_ONLY 1
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <urdl/http.hpp>
#include <urdl/istream.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  urdl::istream is;

  return 0;
}
```

Then I compile I get the following Errors:

in http.ipp from URDL

```
/Users/maximilian/XcodeProjects/Libaries/urdl-0.1/include/urdl/impl/http.ipp:25:23:     Exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
```

and in handler_invole_helpers.hpp from URDL

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:37:3: Call to 'asio_handler_invoke' is ambiguous
```

My suggestion is that URDL is not compatible with this Version of Boost (1.56).

Thanks in Advance

lux_

PS: I must use URDL or at least boost::asio (which URDL is based on, but URDL makes my work much simpler) because it is a homework for an university course.

Comment: Did you try an older version of boost, to confirm your hypothesis? https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/urdl seems to have fixed some issues since the version of urdl you link to.

Comment: Thank you, I have now checked with Boost 1.49 and it works with the URDL I have downloaded (it's from the page of the creator not github). Now I downloaded URDL from the linked github Page and compiled it with Boost 1.56 and it works. Yes the error which is fixed on github was exactly the one, so the problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved ! :) Download the URDL Version from Github instead of the Website think-async.com as I did before.